# Behavior of extended attributes

Tags: command-line, permissions

I don't understand the behavior of extended attributes. Let's say I have a file that does not have rwx access for group.

```
$ ls -lah test.txt
-rw------- 1 sami staff 0 july  5 20:22 test.txt
```

Now I want to give rwx access to a specific user called koti:

```
$ setfacl -m u:koti:rwx test.txt
$ ls -lah test.txt
-rw-rwx---+ 1 sami staff 0 july  5 20:22 test.txt
```

For some reason, now ls shows that group "staff" has rwx access to the file?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's a result of the way `setfacl` re-calculates the *effective rights mask*, but I'm not even going to **try** to explain it... see for example [What relationships do tie ACL mask and standard group permission on a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147499/what-relationships-do-tie-acl-mask-and-standard-group-permission-on-a-file)

Comment: User koti and group staff should have nothing to do with each other. So, I don't see what relationship does there exist that justifies this behavior.

Comment: It looks like that even if there is rwx for group staff, the group staff can not access this file. Perhaps it is just the ls output that is confusing. Not sure though. It is like the group section is saying that "some other has rwx than the file owner"

Comment: If you look at the link steeldriver provided, there's a quote at the end:"In minimal ACLs, the group class permissions are identical to the owning group permissions. In extended ACLs, the group class may contain entries for additional users or groups. This results in a problem: some of these additional entries may contain permissions that are not contained in the owning group entry, so the owning group entry permissions may differ from the group class permissions."  So seems like with `ACL` the `ls -l` only shows part of the story and you need `getfacl` then.

Comment: Yes, it made sense when I realized that those permission bits are not actually showing only group access rights.

Comment: With extended permissions set you can not see actual rights with ls command unless using getfacl. I mean `ls` output in most cases will be misleading.